# Create new user using CLI in magento 2 enterprise version

Tags: magento2, magento-enterprise

below command is working in magento 2 enterprise version ?

```
sudo php bin/magento admin:user:create --admin-user="pearlbells" --admin-password="pear122l**all" --admin-email="pearl@gmail.com" --admin-firstname="Admin" --admin-lastname="Admin"
```

Comment: Yes you can create it by command.

Comment: i able to create user using this command in community version . so same command can i use in enterprise?

Comment: Yes you can same command for enterprise version.

Comment: i getting The "--admin" option does not exists.

Comment: try it without sudo.

Comment: Not working :(.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a new admin user by below command, I have created in eterprise edition

```
php bin/magento admin:user:create --admin-user='pearlbells' --admin-password='pear122lall' --admin-email='pearl@gmail.com' --admin-firstname='Admin' --admin-lastname='Admin'
```

Now you can login with User Name : **pearlbells** and Password : **pear122lall**